# Java Canvas repaint() is flickering

Tags: java, canvas, repaint, flicker

So I finally got a Canvas to work the way I want it but it flickers constantly, repaint() is run 20 times a second and the flicking does lessen when I make it run 10 times a second.

```
package pd.data;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import pd.areas.MainMenu;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

    private Thread gameThread = new Thread(this);
    public boolean running = false;



    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int current = PDU.PD_MAIN_MENU;
    private MainMenu mainmenu;

    public Main() {main.setTitle("PD");
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setLocation(SPU.screenWidth / 2 - SPU.windowSize.width / 2,
                SPU.screenHeight / 2 - SPU.windowSize.height / 2);
        main.setResizable(false);
        main.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(SPU.windowSize);
        main.setContentPane(contentPane);
        main.pack();
        mainmenu = new MainMenu();

        contentPane.add(mainmenu, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.gameThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while (running) {
            {
                mainmenu.repaint();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SPU.TSU);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

And below is my MainMenu class:

```
package pd.areas;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainMenu extends Canvas{

    BufferedImage img = null;
    public MainMenu() {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    }
    public void paint(Graphics graphics){

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(
                    "/image.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        graphics.drawImage(img, this.getWidth() / 2 - img.getWidth()/2, 50, null);
    }

}
```

Although the flicker is actually a nice effect, it's going to effect the whole canvas and not just the image I'm guessing, how can I fix the flicker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't use java.awt.Canvas. Use a JPanel instead.
2. Draw in the JPanel's paintComponent method.
3. Don't forget to call your super's painting method which for `paintComponent` would be  `super.paintComponent(graphics)`
4. **Never** try to read in an image from within any painting method. That will slow down painting and make your program seem unresponsive. Why keep reading in the same image over and over again anyway? Read it in **once** and save it to a variable.

Comment: I did try saving the image to a var but it didn't paint at all after I did, I only moved it to the constructor.

Comment: @FOD: then you will need to fix whatever bug you've got that prevents the image from being drawn, but it's still the right thing to do. Regardless, you should never slow down the paint or paintComponent with non-painting code, not unless you want your program's perceived responsiveness to be poor.

Comment: Would doing an `if(imgisset = false){ //set image; imgisset = true;}` within the paint() stop the slowing of painting?

Comment: @FOD: do not read any files from within paint or paintComponent. Period, end of story, and I really really am not lying to you. Seriously!

Answer (score 0):

Though this thread was opened 5 years ago, it's still going to be an issue for anyone new to Java SE.

I had the same problem with Canvas myself, but wasn't convinced enough to switch to javax components because I recalled a VLC project called JVLC which used Canvas to render videos flawlessly (granted jvlc uses some native code).

**Tip 1:** perhaps it's better to try JPanel instead.

**Tip 2:** in gaming systems, it's better to use a game engine (it'll save you lots of time).

**Tip 3:** in gaming systems, implement a fps mechanism rather than calling repaint() on every change.

**Tip 4:** if you have to call more than 10 lines of code in your paint() implementation you're going to slow it down. It's better to draw to a BufferedImage for every graphical change you need to make to your app, then have the paint() implementation itself draw just the image itself. This should play nicely with an fps mechanism and will reduce the chances of any flickering.

Comment: note the OP didn't have 10 lines of code in their paint, and didn't mention anything about gaming - these are great tips but not really about the question asked.

Comment: I actually found this thread on Google. The topic is on the SE's auto suggestions as soon as you bring up Canvas, and this thread is the first in the list of results. My contribution to this thread was sort of based on that context. The OP's code does seem to suggest it was a game/animation of sorts in the works.

Comment: I found reducing the amount of code in the paint method was the best way to enhance performance where animation is concerned. Using the resources **BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage (width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); Graphics2D canvasGraphics = canvas.createGraphics (); ** does the job well. Best part it can be passed from class to class if such a thing were desirable.

Comment: It's worth noting that while JPanel updates without any flickers (thus the best candidate to replace Canvas), JFrame doesn't do so well with all that updating, and will pull some magic tricks on you. It's better to put the JPanel inside a Frame instead. But to be fair, maybe JFrame is a tad more busier in the background than its predecessor and might actually work fine if you address each and every variable. Example, always use a layout manager, set your preferredSize (), etc.